# Can't turn on Deep Linking for iOS in Facebook Developer

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, applinks

I'm developing an app which supports Facebook applinks. I was able to make it work for android. But for iOS, when I turned on “**Deep Linking**” (Settings -> Basic -> iOS), It didn’t save. It keeps the state as disabled. How to fix this?.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @gpavlov Not yet